# Rename files with function

Tags: python, bash

I would like to rename files in directory using bash.

I am trying:

```
find . -type f -exec mv '{}' $(urlencode {})  \;
```

but urlencode encodes literally `{}` instead of taking result of find.

If changed to:

```
. -type f -exec mv '{}' $(echo {})  \;
```

echo prints result of find.

The urlencode is an alias:

```
$alias urlencode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; \
    print ul.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])"
```

[Decoding URL encoding (percent encoding)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding)

Can anyone explain this behavior and suggest solution?

Comment: >> echo prints result of find. << Nope, it doesn't. Substitution of `$( )` is done before the command is executed and `$(echo {})` part is replaced by its result `{}`, so the second variant just executes `find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'  \;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

```
find . -type f -exec mv '{}' $(echo {})  \;
```

the command substitution is unquoted, so it gets expanded in the command line, before `find` sees it. The resulting command that runs is

```
find . -type f -exec mv '{}' {} \;
```

and then `find` replaces both copies of `{}` with the current file name. The same happens if the command substitution is double-quoted.

If it's single-quoted, however, then `find` will expand the `{}` within it, and run commands like `mv ./somefile $(echo ./somefile)`, which will not work unless the directory `$(echo .` exists.

The main point here is that **`find -exec` doesn't run through a shell**.

You need to ask for a shell there explicitly. Either once per each file

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(urlencode "$1")"' sh {} \;
```

or one shell for multiple files and a loop to deal with them all

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "$(urlencode "$f")"; done' sh {} +
```

Of course, if `urlencode` is an alias, you'll have to jump through hoops to get it to work in a noninteractive shell. It's probably better to put it as a script in the `PATH`, or as an exported function (in which case, run `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`).

Answer (score 2):

Use `bash -c` command:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" $(urlencode "$1")' _ {}  \;
```